# Filter PPPoE packets

Tags: iptables, firewall, ppp, pppd

Can you somehow inspect PPPoE packets and then filter them with iptables or other tools? PPPoE is below ipv4 so I can't use iptables directly.

Comment: I got a bit further. You can pass pppoe packets to iptables with bridge-nf-filter-pppoe-tagged. But filtering does not work.